# Regex match number consisting of specific range, and length?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match a **number** that may consist of `[1-4]`, with a length of `{1,1}`.

I've tried multiple variations of the following, which won't work:

```
/^string\-(\d{1,1})[1-4]$/
```

Any guidelines? Thanks!

Comment: `/^[1-4]$/` is all you would need (based on your description), but I'm guessing there is more.

Comment: Ahh, finally! I thought I had to use `\d` as well.

Comment: `\d` is just shorthand for `[0-9]` (which is just shorthand for `[0123456789]`). It is in no way required.

Comment: Why didn't you make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use:

```
/^string-[1-4]$/
```

Match the start of the string followed by the word "string-", followed by a single number, 1 to 4 and the end of the string. This will match only this string and nothing else.

If this is part of a larger string and all you want is the one part you can use something like:

```
/string-[1-4]\b/
```

which matches pretty much the same as above just as part of a larger string.

You can (in either option) also wrap the character class (`[1-4]`) in parentheses to get that as a separate part of the matches array (when using preg_match/preg_match_all).

Answer (score 1):

This is not hard:

```
/^string-([1-4]{1})$/
```

Comment: The `{1}` is not needed. The character class means one character already. You probably just want to put a `\b` after the character class to prevent multiple numbers.

Comment: Thanks for this insight, Jonathan.